# R suppress names when displaying or printing a named vector

Tags: r

I am wondering if, given a named vector, if it is possible to print (or display in the R console) only the values of the vector without deleting the names.

```
# EXAMPLE
v <- (1:5)
names(v) <- LETTERS[1:5]

print(v)
# RESULT: 
#  A B C D E 
#  1 2 3 4 5 

# RESULT I AM SEEKING 
#  [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

I am able to get the result I am looking for using the following function. 
However, is there a better or more direct way of printing only the values of a named vector?

```
print.n <- function (obj) {
  names(obj) <- NULL
  print(obj)
}

print.n(v)
#  [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try `unname()`:

```
R> v <- (1:5); names(v) <- LETTERS[1:5]
R> print(v)
A B C D E 
1 2 3 4 5 
R> print(unname(v))
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
R>
```