# named Element-wise operations in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and apologize in advance for asking a basic question, but I couldn't find answer anywhere on Google (maybe because the question is so basic that I didn't even know how to correctly search for it.. :D)

So if I do the following in R:

```
v = c(50, 25)
names(v) = c("First", "Last") 
v["First"]/v["Last"]
```

I get the output as:

```
First 
    2
```

Why is it that the name, "First" appears in the output and how to get rid of it?

Comment: One way is `unname(v["First"]/v["Last"])`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316082/r-suppress-names-when-displaying-or-printing-a-named-vector  (and there are many dupes for this)

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289948/bayesfactor-package-r-two-different-output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `help("Extract")`, this is because

> Subsetting (except by an empty index) will drop all attributes except `names`, `dim` and `dimnames`.

and

> The usual form of indexing is `[`. `[[` can be used to select a single element dropping `names`, whereas `[` keeps them, e.g., in `c(abc = 123)[1]`.

Since we are selecting single elements, you can switch to double-bracket indexing `[[` and names will be dropped.

```
v[["First"]] / v[["Last"]]
# [1] 2
```

As for which name is preserved when using single bracket indexing, it looks like it's always the first (at least with the `/` operator).  We'd have to go digging into the C source for further explanation.  If we switch the order, we still get the first name on the result.

```
v["Last"] / v["First"]
# Last 
#  0.5
```