# BayesFactor Package R: Two different Output

Tags: r, bayesian

I'm using the `BayesFactor` package but I get **two different output** for the **same data** using **two very similar codes**. I'm wondering **which one is correct?**

```
if(!require(BayesFactor)){install.packages('BayesFactor')}

require(BayesFactor)
##################################################

exp(ttest.tstat(t= 2 , n1=40, n2=40, nullInterval =c(0, Inf), rscale = sqrt(2)/2,
        complement = FALSE, simple = FALSE)$bf)   ### !CHECK THIS OUTPUT! ###


exp(ttest.tstat(t= 2 , n1=40, n2=40, nullInterval =c(0, Inf), rscale = sqrt(2)/2, 
       complement = FALSE, simple = TRUE))    ### !CHECK THIS OUTPUT! ###
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mentioned in the documentation of `?ttest.tstat`

> If simple is TRUE, returns the Bayes factor (against the null). If
>   FALSE, the function returns a vector of length 3 containing the
>   computed **log(e)** Bayes factor, along with a proportional error estimate
>   on the Bayes factor and the method used to compute it.

In essence, we don't need to take the `exp` when `simple=TRUE`

```
ttest.tstat(t= 2 , n1=40, n2=40, nullInterval =c(0, Inf),
   rscale = sqrt(2)/2, complement = FALSE, simple = TRUE)
#     B10 
# 2.502954
```

whereas with `simple=FALSE`

```
exp(ttest.tstat(t= 2 , n1=40, n2=40, nullInterval =c(0, Inf),
        rscale = sqrt(2)/2, complement = FALSE, simple = FALSE)$bf)
#[1] 2.502954
```